# Macro unable to save results when it is made to run using vbscript

Tags: vba, windows, web-scraping, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I've created a macro to scrape the title of posts from a webpage. The macro runs fine when I try it manually.

However, my intention is to run and save the result using a ***`.vbs`*** file which will be executed through a ***`.bat`*** file so that I can ultimately make use of it through `windows task scheduler`.

When I click on this ***`.bat`*** file to check whether it will work at all, It does open that macro using ***`.vbs`*** and scrape the content as it is supposed to.

**The only problem I'm facing is that I can't make the** `.vbs` **file save the result in that workbook. How can I save the result?***

***`.vbs`*** contains:

```
RunMacro
Sub RunMacro()
  Dim xl, path, xlBook
  path = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
  Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(path & "\basicScraper.xlsm", 0, True)
  xl.Application.Visible = False
  xl.DisplayAlerts = False
  xl.Application.Run "basicScraper.xlsm!MyMacro.GetPosts"
  xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
  xl.ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

***`.bat`*** contains:

```
cscript macro.vbs "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\vba scheduler\macro.vbs"
```

This is the macro I'm working with (module name: `MyMacro`):

```
Sub GetPosts()
    Dim S$, r&, post As Object

    With New XMLHTTP
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each post In .getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")
            r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.innerText
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Found out the solution!!!***

> The `.bat` file should contain:

```
@echo off
echo %~dp0
cd /d %~dp0
"C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\New folder\macro.vbs" "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\New folder\basicScraper.xlsm"
```

> And the `.vbs` file should contain:

```
Dim xl, args

Set args = Wscript.Arguments
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xl.Workbooks.Open args(0)
xl.Application.Visible = False
xl.Application.Run "GetPosts"
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close
xl.Quit
```

> The `basicScraper.xlsm` should be as it is. That's it.

Now, putting the complete address of the ***`.bat`***
file's location to the schedulers ***`program/script`*** inputbox in ***`Action`*** tab will do the trick.

Post script: I kept all three files `.bat`, `.vbs` and `.xlsm` in a single folder before execution and got the result as expected.

Comment: You should mark this as solved if you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@robots.txt
You want to use the Windows Task Scheduler, create a task calling the .vbs

The .vbs should look like

```
Set XLObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLObj.visible = true
XLObj.Workbooks.Open "T:\he\path\to\basicScraper.xlsm"
XLObj.Run "'T:\he\path\to\basicScraper.xlsm'!MyMacro.GetPosts"
XLObj.quit
set XLObj = nothing
```

If I understand your code correctly, you try to insert the inner text of each link into some cells: Try to specify where exactly you want to put it (e.g. Worksheets"(Book 1").Cells(r, 1)).

```
Dim xHttp               As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim hDoc                As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim objCollection       As Object
Dim objElement          As Object
Dim strLink             As String


Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

xHttp.Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions", False
xHttp.send

Do Until xHttp.READYSTATE = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

If xHttp.Status = 200 Then
    Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

    Set objCollection = hDoc.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")

            For Each objElement In objCollection
                strLink = objElement.InnerText
                Worksheets("Book 1").Cells(r, 1) = strLink
                r = r + 1
            Next

End If

ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

You should find your results in Book 1, rows 1 to n.

Comment: Sorry @EarlyBird2, you suggestion didn't work out. Complying your instruction when I run the macro directly from the workbook, it works but when I do the same using `.bat` file I still get that empty.

Comment: Well, all I can say is I am using this approach multiple times/day, works just fine: No matter how you trigger your .vbs - be it via a .bat-file or Task Scheduler - saving the "basicScraper.xlsm" workbook at the end of your macro should do it...

Comment: Just thinking, @robots.txt, why do you need the batch file? You can trigger the .vbs  from the Task Scheduler directly, or am I missing something?